# How to attach a token with WebHttpBinding?

Tags: c#

I have to use webHttpBinding to visit a url used https, which acquires a token.

I used

```
Binding webHttpBinding = new WebHttpBinding
    {
        Security =
        {
            Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport,
            Transport =
            {
                ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None
            }
        }
    };
ChannelFactory<T> factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(WebHttpbinding, my EndpointAddress);
```

So how can I attach a token to my binding or factory?

Comment: Is this using WCF or some other web api?

Comment: Would you consider using `HttpClientReponse` and `HttpClient` to visit that URL? They seem to be designed for attaching a token and calling a url.

Comment: It's using WCF and we cannot using a httpclient to replace the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.webhttpsecuritymode?view=netframework-4.8): "The value of `WebHttpSecurityMode` can only be set in the `WebHttpBinding` constructor that takes it as an explicit parameter and its value cannot be set again after the binding instance is created."

So you probably need to set the mode in your constructor instead of your lambda.
Then the Token is attached to the `ChannelFactory`:

```
Binding webHttpBinding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport)
{
    Security =
    {
        //Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport, //required in the constructor
        Transport =
        {
            ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None
        }
    }
};
ChannelFactory<T> factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(webHttpbinding, my EndpointAddress);

//attach your token/credentials to the factory
factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(GetCredentials());//You haven't shown your code for getting a token
```

Comment: The factory.Credentials is read only,  it cannot be assigned.

Comment: Oh, you are right.  Credentials are added via Endpoint Behaviors.  I've corrected my answer.